# What is C# analog for ColorMatrixFilter in ActionScript?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, actionscript, colormatrixfilter

What is C# (wpf, .NET) analog for [ColorMatrixFilter](https://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/filters/ColorMatrixFilter.html) in ActionScript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the [ColorMatrix class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.colormatrix.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

there's no such built-in thing per se, if I understood correctly. however, you should check out this link: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/Image_Processing_Lab.aspx